# Mapping Excel Sheet Field with my pre defined database fields php

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I am having a number of different excel sheets at my end. I need to put their data in the database. There are some predefined fields in database (country,code,start date, end date) which I need to fetch from excel and need to put in the database.

**Tried so far :**
I have fetched the data and putting it in the database when i know the field names of excel sheets. For example if excel is also having **(country,code,start,end)** then my code is taking and putting in the data base exactly

**Problem**
I want this to be automatic upload to database in case the excel fields are not same as i using in my code. Explaining furhter ,  suppose in my excel fields are  **(location,location code, starting date, end date)**. then I also want my program to extract the data from proper field.

I want some kind of mapping utility at my panel so that admin can map the fields once a new excel sheet with new fields are uploaded. so that it maps and fetch the data from proper columns of excel sheets.

Please suggest how to start it with.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use library like

http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/

And do a custom app which have admin can select the fields in db for the read columns in excel.